# using different domain for static contents?

Tags: domain-name-system

Say my web server is named `example.com`

now I want to use cloudflare cdn for `media.example.com` .

but cloudflare requires to change `example.com` 's name server to cloudflare's, and I can't do that

I could instead use `media.another.com` instead of `media.example.com` . 
(They only point to s3 bucket)

Question is, is it fine to use `example.com` for web service and `media.another.com` for a static contents it serves?

can the host differ? (I know javascript ajax requests don't allow crossing the site, and I wonder something similar is at play here? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not only Ook, it is recommended because this way there is no way cookies from the original domain are sent on every request (which possibly adds a LOT of size to every request).